# Wordpress custom field and user meta comparison operators

Tags: php, wordpress, comparison, operators

I’m trying to query a user field value. Basically I want to use an if statement based on whether the current user ID matches the custom field ID value in order to show user specific content. I’ve had a few goes with some code snippets but I can’t seem to get anything working.

I’ve looked briefly into comparison operators and tried to get the below code to work with no success. New to PHP so be gentle :/

```
<?php 
   $client_id = get_currentuserinfo($user_ID); 
   if ($client_id == get_field('user_select')) : 
?>
<p>Working</p>
<?php else : ?>
<p>Not Working</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help is mega appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This may be as simple as not naming the `$current_user` as a global variable: http://codex.wordpress.org/get_currentuserinfo

In [WordPress for Web Apps](http://cferdinandi.github.io/web-app-starter-kit/), I use this snippet to grab the current user ID:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
```

**reference:** http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user

When you say you want to match the value of a field, where is this field? Is it a form on the front-end? Is it something in the database? I'm not sure that `get_field` is the right function to be using for this.